# Storing 0.00001 in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an earn site and I would like the user to earn 0.00001 per click
(I know it's under 1p).

What type of column could I use? I have tried `int` and `float` but neither works.

Comment: ints don't support non-integer fields, obviously. A float would, so "does not work" means what in this context?

Comment: Use `DECIMAL(x,y)` with y at least 5: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: A `FLOAT` does not have enough precision. `DOUBLE` could do the trick, but the `DECIMAL` type was made for just something like this.

Comment: @Radu: Sure it does, `FLOAT(7,5)` would do just fine. floating point error is another matter, so yeah. decimal type is better suited.

Comment: Marc B: `FLOAT` is good only for math things, when you use arithmetic functions, especially * and / you can get not what you expected.

Answer (score 14):

Use [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html#id758085) for exact values.

The number `0.00001` has 6 digits. 1 before and 5 after the decimal point. Therefore, it would be represented as `DECIMAL(6, 5)` (6 digits out of which 5 are after the decimal point). If you would like to have, say, 4 digits before and 5 digits after the decimal point, you'd use `DECIMAL(9, 5)` (9 in total, out of which 5 are after the decimal point).

Also see:

- [Precision Math](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math.html)
- [Problems with Floating-Point Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html)

Comment: for the record `DECIMAL(5,5)` would do just fine if you only want to store values from `-0.99999` up to `0.99999`

Answer (score 4):

You use INT and divide by 100000 when you display the value.

Comment: @ downvoters: An explanation for voting this down would be nice.

Comment: when im paying the user i don't wanna need to keep doing maths ... how would i display it anyways ?

Comment: @nick: You are counting clicks (an integer value), not pence. Pence is only a representation, so doing "the maths" (if you can even call it that) in the presenation layer (i.e. when you calculate an actual amount) would be in order. Storing `0.000001` in the database and then trying to avoid rounding issues is kind of over-complicated.

Comment: +1 This is a viable solution and avoids [floating-point rounding errors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: @Yeroon: I agree, it's a viable alternative to store `clicks`. Not one I would choose though to store `credit`. OP "clearly" stated that he wants to store how much (0.00001) a user **earns**.

Comment: I agree with Tomalak however if the amount paid per click changes at some point then keeping an integer representation of clicks is useless.

Comment: also agree with @Yeroon, not with @James; if the amount paid per click changes, just change the 'math' (which should not worry you). This is more a matter of choice btw, do you want to store the clicks or the award? But another consideration; do your users earn a reward for other things too? if so, do you want to know how the final reward is built up? if so, you'll have to save the clicks and other rewarding actions and do the math afterwards. bottomline, good suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want a [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html) data type.

Comment: im getting 0 rows affected.
Note: #1265 Data truncated for column 'credit' at row 1  when i try and add 0.00001 into it so can;t use that type

Comment: @Nick: What precision and scale did you specify for the `DECIMAL`? You'd want a scale of at least 5 (digits after the decimal).

Comment: @nick: how did you define the decimal field? You'd want something like `DECIMAL(7,5)`. (7 digits of which 5 come after the decimal place: xx.xxxxx)

Comment: @nick: Defining `credit` as `DECIMAL(8,5)` will allow you to store 8-digits numbers with 5 digits after decimal point, e.g. numbers from `-999.99999` to `999.99999`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the decimal column type with a value of (9,5), where 9 is the total number of digits (before and after the decimal place) and  5 is how many digits come after the decimal place. For more information on this column type, check out the MySql documentation page:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: SQL query:

ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `credit` `credit` DECIMAL( 4, 5 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
getting this error 
MySQL said: Documentation
#1427 - For float(M,D), double(M,D) or decimal(M,D), M must be >= D (column 'credit').