# MySQL DECIMAL handling in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point, decimal, precision

As commonly discussed, (for example here [Storing 0.00001 in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203114/storing-0-00001-in-mysql) ) the DECIMAL data-type should be used for fields where precision / correctness is required, such as an account balance.

I was wondering however, how PHP handles these values and, if they are internally handled as floats, if there is still a problem when reading these values from the database, doing some calculations and writing them back again. If so, how can we force PHP to keep precision in tact?

Comment: We now do all calculations inside the MySQL queries when entering them into the database. Some imprecision still remains so maybe the issue lies somewhere else, but that's another question I guess..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The variable is probably a string initially in PHP (when read from the MySQL result object). In general, PHP's floating-point datatype cannot be relied upon to keep the precise decimal value required. You should use an arbitrary-precision mathematics library like [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php). (When you fetch a row of the result object, pass the `DECIMAL` column value in to the appropriate constructor, and then operate on it using the functions provided by the library you are using.)

To go more into depth: Suppose you have an amount stored in the database, in a `DECIMAL(6, 4)` column. You want to fetch that into PHP, to do something with it. You issue a query to fetch that column. You fetch the first row of the query into an associative array. Suppose that the value from that row is `2.5674`. Your array is now something like `array('MyDecimal' => '2.5674')` (the number appears as a string). You use (as far as I can tell) `gmp_init()` to convert that string to a GMP resource. Now you can do mathematics with that number using the other GMP functions. If you want to store a GMP number, you could convert it back to string using `gmp_strval()` (perhaps you do not have to do this if you are using a database abstraction layer that can handle GMP resources).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the arbitrary precision features:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Your other option is to store the values as INTs and then convert them when they need to be displayed (i.e. divide by one hundred).